# many .cpp file are creating .o files containing the destructor for a boost::optional<myPosition> despite they are not referencing it

Tags: c++, linux, templates, g++

I've counted how often certain weak symbols occur in some project. I'm doing this to reduce build time. It was standing out that a certain destructor for `boost::optional<myPosition>` was created in many .o files. So I investigated. Many were not referencing this destructor nor creating an object of this type.
Anybody any clue?
I used `objdump -dC objectFileName.o` to look at the generated assembly code. As I said -- no reference.

How can this be avoided?
Only via encapsulating this functionality in a separate class and using only a pointer to it so that the implementation is free to use `boost::optional<myPosition>`?

Comment: Check for code that includes a header file that would cause the type to be defined.

Comment: Edit the header file, put in a `#error How did you get here`, compile, and see what happens.

Comment: How did you conclude that it was not "creating an object of this type"? Did you check every object that was created, to make sure that it doesn't containing this specific object as a class member? Did you check every expression to make sure that it does not create this object, or anything that contains this object, as a temporary object?

Answer (score 0):

Linking the object file in question into a dummy shared library resolved the problem of apparently unused code. disassembling the shared library showed very nicely who is calling the symbol in question. This was not the case when disassembling the .o file in question.

Comment: Your question *"How can this be avoided?"* was ambiguous. It's great you resolved your own question, but unfortunately, only you knew what you wanted to avoid.

Comment: @jxh This happens when one asks the question before knowing the solution.

Comment: In this case, you wanted to avoid sorting through cases where the destructor was unused. Whereas I think most people would interpret the question as meaning to avoid generating the destructor in object files that were not using it.